# hover menu not persistent in IE10, 9

Tags: css, menu, hover

I have created a very basic hover css menu for a joomla site (I don't really want to get into jQuery if I can avoid it). It works fine in everything except IE (10,9...).

When you hover over the top level and move the move over the child menu the child menu persists in everything except IE.

How do I get IE to play ball?0

Here's the html:

```
    <ul class="menu" id="mainMenu">
<li class="item-210"><a href="/index.php/home-2" >Home</a></li>
<li class="item-213 current active deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/xbus2" >xBus</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="item-214"><a href="/index.php/xbus2/vision" >Vision</a></li>
        <li class="item-215"><a href="/index.php/xbus2/timetable" >Timetable</a></li>
        <li class="item-217"><a href="/index.php/xbus2/xbus-mini" >xBus Mini</a></li>
        <li class="item-218"><a href="/index.php/xbus2/xbus2" >xBus2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li><li class="item-220 deeper parent"> etc ....
```

and here's the css

```
ul#mainMenu li {
    position:relative;
}

ul#mainMenu ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    top:17px;
    left:-9999px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:5;

}

ul#mainMenu ul li {
    display:block;
    border-top:1px solid #999;
}

ul#mainMenu ul li:first-child {
    border-top:none;
}

ul#mainMenu ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2em;
    color:pink;
}

ul#mainMenu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the margin and padding to zero. IE has default value about this.

'ul#mainMenu ul {padding:0; margin: 0;}'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no margin between the elements which could be causing the issue. The IE dev tools will help with this.

Also, try applying a 1px transparent gif or png as the background of the child LI's - http://www.welovecss.com/showthread.php?s=4de6205bc9ac3ff2ead50464d123bcf4&t=6478&page=2

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had a look - no margins. But I set the top level li elements to display:inline-block; and now all appears well.